# How to set padding or margin on this text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a website that uses the Bootstrap `navbar`. I want the brand name to be slightly lower to better align with the brand image.

[image]

I understand the text is vertically centered but because there are no letter going down it feels not aligned to the icon. When adding padding or margin the text remains in the same position and I don't get why. I removed all my in vain attempts to just have the required code left. I tried using padding, margin, line-height but nothing worked. A complete live preview of the design can be found here: https://www.steemmakers.com/test/Home.html

How can I slightly move the text down?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-primary navbar-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand d-block d-md-none" href="#" style="display: block; font-family: 'Rajdhani', sans-serif; font-weight:700; font-size:25px; color:white">
      <img src="steemmakers_icon_white.svg" height="56px"> SteemMakers 
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-brand d-none d-md-block" href="#" style="display: block; font-family: 'Rajdhani', sans-serif; font-weight:700; font-size:40px; color:white">
      <img src="steemmakers_icon_white.svg" height="56px"> SteemMakers 
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: use line-height property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is surround the SteemMakers text with a span tag, and apply the following styles to it:

```
position: relative;
top: 3px;
```

Just tested it using the Chrome Dev Tools, let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: Thank you, this seems like the most simple solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your brand name `SteemMakers` besides logo on an span and then you can add padding-top on it. Here is the html and css for you

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-primary navbar-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand d-block d-md-none" href="#" style="display: block; font-family: 'Rajdhani', sans-serif; font-weight:700; font-size:25px; color:white">
      <img src="steemmakers_icon_white.svg" height="56px"> <span class="brand-name">SteemMakers</span> 
    </a>
    <a class="navbar-brand d-none d-md-block" href="#" style="display: block; font-family: 'Rajdhani', sans-serif; font-weight:700; font-size:40px; color:white">
      <img src="steemmakers_icon_white.svg" height="56px"> SteemMakers 
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Sample CSS for brand name

```
.brand-name {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 1;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In html there is `img` inside `a` tag and text by which it is little hard to set the text alignment as both will align respect to `a` tag. but you can do one thing that move `img` according to your requirement.

Set

```
img {
  position: relative;
  top: -3px;
}
```

Use `top bottom left right` to move image with respect to text as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This should move image up/down, work well in all viewports

```
.navbar-brand img {
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```